# C++ Check if String contains atleast 1 digit and 1 letter

Tags: c++

I am trying to check if a string input contains atleast one numeric digit and one letter before returning true.

My approach was first by looping through the word.
If the word does not contain either `isalpha` or `isdigit` then return false.

After that check, I create two counts (One for digits and one for letters). I check if `isalpha` then add one to the count. I then check if `isdigit` and add to that count.

Finally I check if both counts are greater than or equal to 1 (Meaning it contains atleast one digit and one letter) and return true. I know counts are not the best method but I am just trying to test the method but it fails to work and I'm not sure where my logic is wrong.

```
bool isDigitLetter::filter(string word) {
    int digit = 0;
    int letter = 0;
    if(word.empty()) {
        return false;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(!isalpha((unsigned char)word[i]) || !isdigit((unsigned char)word[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)word[x])) {
                letter+=1;
        }
        if(isdigit((unsigned char)word[x])) {
            digit+=1;
        }
    }
    if(digit && letter>= 1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I was thinking maybe using `isalnum` but that would return true if it contains either but not checking if it contains atleast one of each.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the program. See where things differ from what you expect and examine that line in more detail.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: `if(digit && letter>= 1)` this will always be true

Comment: `bool isDigitLetter::filter(std::string word){ return std::any_of(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c){ return std::isalpha(c); }) && std::any_of(word.begin(), word.end(), [](char c){ return std::isdigit(c); }); }`

Comment: "At least 1" does not require a complete count. A single loop is sufficient; it just has to keep track of **whether** it's seen a digit and a letter, and once it's seen both, it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool isDigitLetter::filter(string word) {
    bool hasLetter = false;
    bool hasDigit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(word.at(i))) { hasDigit = true; }
        if (isalpha(word.at(i))) { hasLetter = true; }
    }
    return (hasLetter && hasDigit);
}
```

This solution removes a lot of unnecessary code.

Basically, it loops through the string and checks if each character is a letter or a number. Each time it sees one, it updates the hasLetter/hasDigit variable. It then returns true if both are true and false otherwise.

EDIT: this solution is faster - if it has already seen a letter and a digit, it returns instantly.

```
bool isDigitLetter::filter(string word) {
    bool hasLetter = false;
    bool hasDigit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        if (isdigit(word.at(i))) { hasDigit = true; }
        if (isalpha(word.at(i))) { hasLetter = true; }
        if (hasDigit && hasLetter) { return true; }
    }
    // we got here and couldn't find a letter and a digit
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe in your if statements you are missing one parentheses? You open 3 but close 2 in total.

Comment: hmm, let me see

Comment: aswell as a semi colon on your return (Before the edit)

Comment: oh ok found it - fixing... edited - is this good? @godlycplusplus

Comment: That's it. Aswell as the semi colon after the `return (hasLetter && hasDigit)`

Comment: Oh yeah. And this, children is why you always use an IDE. :P

Comment: Thank you, really nice code and +1 for providing the alternate solution than using counts.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
bool isDigitLetter::filter(string word) {

    int digit = 0;
    int letter = 0;
    if(word.empty()) {
        return false;
    }
//    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
//        if(!isalpha((unsigned char)word[i]) || !isdigit((unsigned char)word[i])) {
//            return false;
//        }
//    }
    for(int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)word[x])) {
                letter+=1;
        }
        if(isdigit((unsigned char)word[x])) {
            digit+=1;
        }
    }
    return ((digit > 0) && (letter > 0));
}
```

Comment: The loop can also terminate early if both `letter` and `digit` become greater than 0.

Comment: Note, also, that the parenthes in the `return` statement are redundant. `return digit > 0 && letter >0;` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: only joking, no offence :)

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o -- redundant parentheses make code **harder** to read; you have to figure out whether they really mean something. Beginners like them, but programmers do not stay beginners, and need to learn to write code without adding distractions.

Comment: yes, the amazing gains to any system from a 0.1 microsecond boost. :)

Comment: You've commented out my first few lines. Does that mean they are redundant or is that causing the problem?

Comment: @godlycplusplus The if condition always returns true, so the function always return false, and right after inspecting the very first char.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this line:

```
if(digit && letter>= 1)
```

Change it to:

```
if(digit >=1 && letter>= 1)
```

Comment: Hmm ... not exactly.

Comment: `if (digit)` is equivalent to `if (digit != 0)`; yes, that's not the same as checking `>= 1` since it's also true for negative values of `digit`, but since `digit` starts at 0 and only goes up, they do the same thing.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it a better answer. That line isn't the problem.

Comment: @SandraK I know it was a logical error, but accidentally it did not impact the code execution. Has to be corrected, anyway.